# Force IOException to happen in Android while reading a file without mocking

Tags: java, android, ioexception

How to make `IOException` happen for testing? In particular, my app is reading a file on the external storage. Is it possible, for example, to instruct the OS to close the file handle for this specific app process so the next `read()` throws an `IOException`?

On a real device, this can be done physically, by removing the external storage media.

Comment: I guess you could deliberately throw IOException and use it for testing. Create a method for reading a file, which inturn uses java api for file reading. Let that method successfully read the file, but your method would deliberately throw IOException.

Comment: you want to throw IOException manually then use throw new IOException()

Comment: I should add that no modification of the app is allowed. Because allowing modification of the app is the same as mocking, which is not intended for the purpose of this question.